# jQuery - Passing parameters to click, with custom function

Tags: jquery

Sorry, this was a bad question.  I couldn't work out how to delete it.  Actual question and solution here:

[jQuery - Toggle div class on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911416/jquery-toggle-div-class-on-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to rebind functions.

Either you bind the click event to a function called toggleSection() which hides the section if it is visible or shows if hidden, or just use this:

```
$('.section.hidden').click(function() {
    $(this).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can just use

```
$('.section-legend, .section-collapse').click(hidesection);
```

and

```
function hideSection() {
    $(this).addClass('hidden');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery offers an easier way to achieve what you want to do:

[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

That way you don't have to implement the changing by hand, but rather work with one click-binding

If of course you would want to just hide and show an object, you could also use

[.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle)

instead of coding it by hand.
That is mostly what Javascript-Frameworks do for you, they implement existing functions, that you can tap into, instead of implementing them yourself. Also cross-browser incompatibilities are taken care of (mostly).

If you really want to use jQuery to its fullest potential, please dig through [**The jQuery API**](http://api.jquery.com/) to get to know all the functions it has to offer. That way you will save a lot of time, that you otherwise would put into developing already existing functions.

Answer (score 0):

Just use toggle, if all you need is visibility. If you have custom css for hiding sections, use toggleClass. To illustrate

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('p').click(function () {
            $('#book').toggle();



            // In javascript, just like many C-derived languages, you can pass 
            // the method's pointer to a variable in. 
            // hidden is the custom class you add and remove from a section
            f = $('#great').is('.hidden') ? funky : hacky;

            f($(this));



            $('#great').toggleClass('hidden');

            $('#amazing').toggleClass('man');

            alert($('#great').attr('class') + ' ---- ' + $('#amazing').attr('class'));
        });


        function funky(section) {
            $(section).html('this is funky!');
        }

        function hacky(section) {
            $(section).html('this is hacky!');
        }

    });
</script>

<div id='book' style='display: none'>Hello</div>

<div id='great' class='diz hidden whatever'>Hai</div>
<div id='amazing' class='spider'>Hai</div>

<p>Stackoverflow rules!</p>
```

If you want the section to start hidden, put `style=display: none` to the tag. For your custom hiding/formatting, use toggleClass.