# jQuery - Toggle div class on click

Tags: jquery

No, this is not a straight forward toggle question.  I am aware of the toggle() functions and how to simply hide/show a div.  Imagine a box with a label inside:

```
<div class="section hidden">
    <div class="section-legend">My Section</div>
</div>
```

When you click anywhere on the entire div, it should remove class `hidden`.  The box then looks expanded.  Now that the box is not of class `hidden` it should not be clickable.

Instead, when you click the `div.section-legend` it should add class `hidden` to the main div again.  Obviously the click event for the legend needs to stopPropagation(). Now the legend should not be clickable anymore and once again you must click the entire div to open it.

I can't get anything to work properly, and I know this is stupid code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.section.hidden').click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hidden');
        $(this).find('.section-legend').click(function(e) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('hidden');
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    });

    $('.section-legend').click(function(e) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('hidden');
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).parent().click(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('hidden');
        });
    });
```

});

Comment: People are getting lazy with always wanting a jsfiddle..

Comment: is a div.hidden still visible somehow? I'm not sure how it's meant to be still clickable if it's really 'hidden'

Comment: It's not really hidden, `hidden` is just the name of the class for the collapsed section.  There is some other code that would mean it makes more sense, but here I can see how it looks confusing.

Comment: it has nothing to do with laziness... it helps solving questions like yours...

Comment: Making a JSFiddle to help people solve your issue isnt lazy its just making it far easier for those who want to help understand your problem rather than garbled code that makes no sense with no context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.section-legend').live('click',function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

This is assuming the section-legend is just as large as it's container in 'hidden state'.

EDIT: changed some code, solution is this:

```
$('.section').live('click',function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hidden');
});
$('.section-legend').live('click',function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('hidden'); return false;
});
```

`return false` did the trick!
demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RUfN7/2/

Comment: No, `section-legend` does not fill the entire container, that's the problem.  It's just a label inside the larger box, that gets moved to the top of the box when you expand it (i.e. no class `hidden`).

Answer (score 1):

First add an onclick event on the div that needs clicking:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="section hidden">
    <div class="section-legend" onclick="function1();">My Section</div>
</div>
```

And add this javascript to the html

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function function1(){
        document.getElementById("myDiv").removeAttribute("class");

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.section').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hidden');
});

$('.section-legend').click(function(e) {
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    if(!$parent.hasClass('hidden')) {
        $parent.addClass('hidden');
        return false;
    }
});
```