# First click shows value when you click for the second timeit will change the value and the third time will reset

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying do change my hamburger icon inside the button in nav when I first click it it will be a right icon by using transform,then after the second click it will show the nav menu.  all can I do is when you hover the hamburger menu it will transform to a right icon, but I want is when it click it will change the icon then the second click will show the nav and after the third it will close the nav.

```
<button id="responsive-menu-button">
<span class="responsive-menu-inner"></span>
</button>
```

this is is my jquery, It's not working, but it's suppose to be like this,when I click the hamburger icon it will change the icon to this ">" I'm using a transform css to be like that, then when I click it for the second time it will show the nav and the icon will be "<" or "x" then when I press it it will be back in hamburger icon

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 if($('.responsive-menu-inner').data('clicked')) {
 $("html").removeClass(" responsive-menu-open");
 $("#responsive-menu-button").removeClass("is-active");
  $("html").addClass("changeicon");
}
else {
$("html").addClass(" responsive-menu-open");
$("#responsive-menu-button").addClass("is-active");
 $("html").removeClass("changeicon");
}

});
```

the responsive-menu-open is class that will open the nav, when it click, the is-active class is the icon for "<" or "x" I don't want to them to show in first click, they will show after the second click

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911416/jquery-toggle-div-class-on-click ?

Comment: different concept, the one you send is toogle, only hide the section of div, I want is to postpone the showing of div when it user click it first but in second time it show the div